# Can't get array index using indexOf in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an array containing all timestamps rounded by minute in a day (~1440 entries). I need to get the index of current minute.

A breif of the array (from console) is like:

```
0: 1516048200
1: 1516048260
2: 1516048320
3: 1516048380
```

I have tried:

```
function time() {
  var timestamp = Math.floor(new Date().getTime() / 1000);
  return timestamp;
}
neededIndex = time_arr.indexOf(function(){return Math.round(time()/60)*60;})); // returns -1
```

I get the current minute using `Math.round(time()/60)*60`.

```
neededIndex = time_arr.indexOf(1516054200); // works fine though
```

What am i missing?

Comment: Because, `Array.prototype.indexOf` does not take a function but rather a value to find. You want `Array.protoype.findIndex`.

Comment: Why do you need to find the index in the array in the first place - it is a known array and a known value in the given timestamp - you can perform a calculation on the timestamp value to identify the index of that minute within the 24 hour timeframe - much faster than comparing the values of the array each time.

Comment: @AluanHaddad then how Durga's code works?

Comment: @Saberi Durga's code does not pass a function it passes the result of calling a function. Read up on the IIFE, a common and powerful JavaScript idiom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];
console.log(arr.indexOf((function() {
  return 2;
})()))
```

Put your function as self invoking function. Then it will work. As your function never called, so it doesn't return anything.

```js
var date = new Date();
var time = date.getTime();
var midNight = date.setHours(0,0,0,0);
console.log(Math.trunc((time - midNight)/1000 /60))
```

You no need to put in array and find the index. Find current time and subtract from midnight and convert to minute.

Comment: i know this works. the problem is with that `Math.round(time()/60)*60` instead of direct value of timestamp!

Comment: @Saberi you can return that `Math.round(time()/60)*60` value.

Comment: Not sure why you would use this.

Answer (score 0):

[Array.prototype.indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) does not take a function but rather a value to find. You should use [Array.protoype.findIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) instead.

For example

```js
"use strict";
const values = [4, 5, 2];

const indexOfFive = values.findIndex(value => value === 5);

console.log(`indexOfFive: ${indexOfFive}`);
```

Note that `Array.prototype.findIndex` was added by ES2015. That means that you will need a polyfill for older runtimes. For example

```
"use strict";

if (typeof Array.prototype.findIndex !== 'function') {
  Array.prototype.findIndex = function findIndex(predicate) {
    if (typeof predicate !== 'function') {
      throw TypeError('Predicate must be a function');
    }
    return this.filter(predicate)[0];
  };
}
```

Comment: now I get: Uncaught TypeError: 1516089480 is not a function

Comment: @Saberi Then you are using an older runtime that does not support that function (it was added in ES2015). You can add it yourself.

Comment: @Saberi I added a polyfill.

Answer (score 0):

As I said in the comments - if you have an array that is every minute within a 24 timeframe (starting at 0 and having 1 entry per minute - totalling 1440 entries) - then you don't need to compare the current minute at all to find the index - use (getHours() * 60) and add getMinutes() to get the current minute within the 24 hour timeframe  and then subtract 1 due to the zero indexing of the array.

For example - it is 7:15 pm here so using this function returns 1154 when it is run (ie: it is the 1155th minute) but due to the zero index of the array - that is the value of the 1154th element of the array.

Note that I am using a for loop to gerate the minutes array - from 0 to 1439 (due to zero indexation).

```js
var minuteArray = [];

for (i=0; i<1440; i++){
  minuteArray.push(i);
}


function timeIndex() {
  var now= new Date();
  var minuteIndex = ((now.getHours()*60) + now.getMinutes())-1;
  return minuteIndex ;
}

var timeIndex = timeIndex();

console.log('timeIndex = ' +timeIndex);
console.log('value of minute array at this index = ' + minuteArray[timeIndex]);
```